# JVM XX:MaxNewSizemax heap size and Xmx

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I launched my java application using the parameter

```
-Xmx700m
```

I get when I try to verify that the value has been correcly set:

```
# jcmd 12164 VM.flags
12164:
-XX:CICompilerCount=3 -XX:InitialHeapSize=58720256 -XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MaxHeapSize=933232640 -XX:MaxNewSize=310902784 -XX:MinHeapDeltaBytes=524288 -XX:NewSize=19398656 -XX:OldSize=39321600 -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

So the MaxHeapSize is not equal to the Xmx value. Am I missing something?

Comment: your config is correct . try this : $ java -XX:InitialHeapSize=128m -XX:MaxHeapSize=2g MyApp

Comment: I found the issue: -Xmx was at the end of the command line (after MyApp) in your example. I looked everywhere and I now know the internals of the garbage collector. lol.